# Angular JS Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need create a directive in Angular JS to paginate a list of objects. But, I want have the control over how the list will be looks like. Something like that, like JSF dataTable componente:

```
<ng-page list="lista" var="item">

<!-- this part keeps in original document -->
    item.name + item.value

<!-- controllers to navigate between the pages, this part is in a template --> 

</ng-page>
```

So the ideia is create a template of pagination, but how the data will be displayed keeps in the document where the table really are. I don't know if I make me understand.

Comment: look into angularui: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

Comment: But for each page I want to create with pagination I'll need to create all the methods in a controller that the pagination componente needs. What I want is create a directive that encapsulates all the logic to paginate, and the page that uses the directive just need to provide the list and the visualization of the data.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use specifically Angular JS for this ? Pagination controls are provided out of the box by UI libraries. I highly recommend bootstrap. Its very light, easy to maintain and minimum coding required for customization.